# Return imacros Extracted value back to php in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, imacros

iMacros code test.js

```
var macro = "CODE:";
macro += "SET !VAR0 hi" + "\n";
macro += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR0}}" + "\n";
iimPlay(macro1)
var result=iimGetLastExtract();
```

Php code testing.php

```
$s = $iim1->iimPlay('test.js');
```

How can i get the content of !VAR0 in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can use this code in test.js to save a csv file

```
var macro = "CODE:";
macro += "SET !VAR0 hi" + "\n";
macro += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR0}}" + "\n";
macro1 += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE =*" + "\n";
iimPlay(macro1)
```

And use php to open that csv file to get the content I want